# How to compare two lists of strings in a dataframe for any matches to get a True or False in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have two columns in a dataframe that consist of lists of strings. I want to compare all items in the lists to see if there are any matches and return a True/False (or any other flag) column to highlight any matches.

I tried to do this by creating sets and comparing them by row, but I keep getting a "False", when it should return "True" ('a' is in column one and two, so it should be True). How can I compare these two lists?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [['a','bb','b','v'], ['aa','b','c','e']],
                  'two': [['b','aa','a','d'],['b','w','f']]})

df['one'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['one']), axis=1)
df['two'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['two']), axis=1)

df['check'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['one'] in row['two'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

I'm expecting a new column, with an output of True, as there are items in the list that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in your `apply`

```
lambda row: bool(row['one'] & row['two']), axis=1
```

Here, as `row['one']` and `row['two']` are already converted to set, `&` performs intersection operation between `row['one']` and `row['two']`

Comment: +1 from me because it solves the problem, but it could use a little explanation as to _why_ it works to help OP or other readers understand

Comment: @G.Anderson, reload the page and get the explanation. :D